# Wildfly compatibility with older versions of Java

Tags: java, wildfly-8

I wanted to migrate from JBOSS EAP to a Wildfly version which supports older versions of Java like 6 or 5.

I can't find a compatibility matrix with wild fly and java.

What about wildfly 8 ? does it supports java older versions.

can someone point me to the matrix where I can find wildfly compatibility with Java

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know Wildfly 8 only supports Java 8+ while JBoss 7 only runs on Java up to 7 due to some "hooking" into JVM internals. So if you want to upgrade to Wildfly you'd also have to upgrade to a newer Java version. That normally should be easier than the Wildfly upgrade but it depends on what your code is doing - if it is tied to a certain Java version you might want to fix that anyway.

Comment: @Thomas so according to you, What is the latest JBoss version which supports for java 6 or older versions ?

Comment: I can't tell for EAP since we've always used community editions but if I remember correctly it should be JBoss 6 or 7. However, for security reasons among others you'd normally want to upgrade to a newer Java version which in most cases should be a smooth operation at least if you upgrade to 8 (of course there might still be hiccups such as `compare()` methods being reported as not adhering to the contract or internal classes having been removed - but that's actually a good thing in most cases).

Comment: WildFly only works with Java 8. JBoss EAP 7 also requires Java 8. Only JBoss EAP 6 or JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final would work with Java 6.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I think Wildfly 8 supports java 7. Could you please share any link where compatibility matrix mentioned.

Comment: It could be Java 7, however Java 7 is no longer supported and WildFly 8 is quite old now. I'm not aware of a compatibility matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest thing to a compatibility matrix I can find. Which has a separate chart for both Wildfly and JBoss EAP:
[Choosing the right JDK for WildFly and JBoss EAP 7](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/wildfly-8/choosing-the-jdk-for-wildfly-and-jboss-eap-7/#:%7E:text=WildFly%20versions%20up%20to%2026,Java%2011%20and%20Java%2017.)

It's obviously not official, but something is better than nothing.